# Saving TextBox content in a text file C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I created this form that allows me to open a txt file and puts the content in a TextBox.
I want to be able to modify the content writing in the textbox and then save it using the SaveFileDialog.
Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
                System.IO.StreamReader input = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                TextBox_stampa_contenuto.AppendText(input.ReadToEnd());
                input.Close();
            }
        }

        private void salva_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){
            string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            File.WriteAllText(name, TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text);

        }
    }

}
```

When I run it works perfectly opening the file, but after I modify it and try to save it doesn't work. The content stays the same. There's a way to fix it? And also how can I put the text in the textbox in write mode and not in append mode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

**Solution 1:** if you want to Save the contents of Textbox into TextFile you need to check  the `DialogResult` return type of the `SaveDialog`.

```
private void salva_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            File.WriteAllText(name, TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text);
        }
 }
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to Insert the File Text into Textbox whithout appending you need to Assign the File String into TextBox `Text` property.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Text_Editor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ladenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "*.txt|*.txt";
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog(richTextBox1);
            string test = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
            richTextBox1.Text = test;

        }
        private void speichernToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(name, Tex.Text);
            }
            /*Stream myStream;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    // Code to write the stream goes here.
                    myStream.Close();
                }
            }
        */
        }

        private void beendenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}












namespace Text_Editor
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // dateiToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem,
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem,
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem});
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem.Name = "dateiToolStripMenuItem";
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 20);
            this.dateiToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Datei";
            // 
            // ladenToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem.Name = "ladenToolStripMenuItem";
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 22);
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Laden";
            this.ladenToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ladenToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // speichernToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem.Name = "speichernToolStripMenuItem";
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 22);
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Speichern";
            this.speichernToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.speichernToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // beendenToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem.Name = "beendenToolStripMenuItem";
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 22);
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Beenden";
            this.beendenToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.beendenToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 426);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion
        private RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private ToolStripMenuItem dateiToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem ladenToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem speichernToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem beendenToolStripMenuItem;
        private MenuStrip menuStrip1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Additionally, please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers, such as yourself given it's been posted 8 years ago, of this post.