# How do i get input from "textbox1" to a .bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I'm new to programming and I want to learn with c# for now, I want to make a program that take the input "the user" put in "textbox1" in to my test.bat file

Text in "test.bat"

```
Set A="textbox1.text" 
Echo %A%
```

Here's the [image of the ui in the visual basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chQeH.jpg) I wrote with the textbox

With the "button1" click it will start the test.bat and show the textbox1 text in the cmd if its possible

I would love to get it to work.

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to use c# to create and run a batch file to show a message in the console? Isn't that a bit like buying a Ferrari, bolting it to your old Volkswagen Beetle and using it to push the Beetle to the shops? Why not just drive the Ferrari to the shops?

Answer (score 0):

Your desires can be met with a couple of lines of code employing the [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0) to create the file with its contents and the [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) method to run it. Ctrl-F on that page for `/k` if you're having trouble getting your console window to remain open to actually see the message

I'll leave the task of formulating the string contents to be written to the file, to you. Remember that the documentation usually has examples on how to use every method it describes so a ready source of pre written code is available

Final tip; you're allowed to rename controls after you drop them on a form, and you really should take the 2 seconds needed to do so, so that you aren't one day asking us for help with code that is full of label27, textbox56 - it makes a program far harder for everyone to understand (look up what "obfuscation" is), including you, and is nonsensical when it's so easy to rename them to `batchFileMessageTextBox` or `saveAndLaunchBatFileButton`

Comment: Hey, i have tryed the writeall function but i couldn't get it to work with my input from the "textbox", thank you for the tips :) !

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\my.txt", "Textbox says: " + userInputTextBox.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding,you want to use C# to create a dialog box to take user input and show  it in console,well its not possible directly but you can store the input given by user in a file and then use a batch file to read it.i am not a c# programmer so i don't know how to work with dialog box in c# but the [Following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495588/saving-textbox-content-in-a-text-file-c-sharp) provides your solution and then use the following batch file to read the input in file:

```
@echo off
set /p var=<file.txt
echo %var%
pause >nul
```

Comment: Nice alternative to the FOR /F command! No problems with delimiters.  (If someone puts multiple lines into file.txt then yours will see only the first line, while mine will only remember the last one. :^)

Comment: yeah,i always got confused when i used for  loop,its far more efficient and thnx

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of simple approaches to this.  One is to do what you asked; to write the input text to a file named "textbox1.text" (really should be "textbox1.txt", though, since ".txt" is a common suffix for text files and ".text" isn't) and then let the batch script read it.

It's a whole lot easier to simply write the text to the standard output stream using `Console.WriteLine()` and let the batch file capture that and do what it wants with the text.  Either way, you're going to need a character that's known *not* to ever be an input character.

I'll give the second approach as an example, but I won't use Forms or WPF.  It's too hard to show what goes where.  You seem to want a window with a text box, though, so I'll use the following "ConsoleApp1.cs" program and borrow the InputBox() function from Visual Basic (a neat console CS trick on its own!):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string answer = Interaction.InputBox("Tell me something");
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile that into a .exe file and copy it to the directory you're using for running .bat files.  Now try the following within a batch file:

```
rem @echo off
for /F "delims=~" %%t in ('ConsoleApp1.exe') do set a=%%t
echo.%a%
```

That's the easy way to get one line of text from a CS program into the .bat file that called it.  If you insist on having the CS program create a text file named "textbox1.text", go ahead.  Look up how to use the `StreamWriter` class to do that.  Then your `.bat` file will use a slightly different form of the `FOR` command:

```
for /F "delims=~" %%t in (textbox1.text) do set a=%%t
```

Either way, you need the character after `delims=` to be a delimiter character that will not by typed by the user.  The `FOR /F` command always parses input lines into tokens separated by whatever delimiter characters you specify (or spaces by default). I use either ~ or ' as characters that don't normally show up in commands or file names.

Justaus3r made a valuable suggestion to use a redirected `SET /P` command.  You can use that, with the above CS program to get the `Console.WriteLine` output into a variable with no delimiter worries:

```
ConsoleApp1.exe >textbox1.text
set /P a=<textbox1.text
```

That works.  Piping output from ConsoleApp1 directly to SET ought to work too, but for some reason it doesn't. I've had a number of issues with old batch files that worked in Win7 that don't in Win10.  This fails in both CMD and PowerShell, though, so there's something weirder going on that MS just isn't maintaining CMD any more.

Comment: Hey, probably im not so good at explaining haha, i try to make like a .txt maker and i need there generic input from the "ui" of the visual studio, for example i have line 10 and i want it to take the in put of textbox1 (for example) so it will write in the .bat file "set A= "textbox1 text" " (im sorry im from my phone)